# React-router history.push does not actually redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want my app to redirect a user on form submit.
I have AuthPage conponent:

```
const AuthPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const test = () => {
    history.push("/boards");
  };

  const submitHandler = () => {
    fetch(...)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        history.push("/boards");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="AuthPage">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        // my form here
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I set `onSubmit={test}` - everything works fine, redirect works. But when I set `onSubmit={submitHandler}` instead - `history` object gets updated, but the redirect actually doesn't happen. I noticed that for a milisecond my client url changes from where I was (`/`) to `/boards`, but than instantly gets back, so I actually stay on the same page. Any ideas on why can that happen?

Comment: Submit event, by default, reloads the browser window; you need to prevent this default behaviour as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [preventing the default refresh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of a submitted form:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
};
```